# Modify Rails scaffolding so that the create and update actions can receive a JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to modify the basic Rails scaffolding so that it can accept a JSON string passed to the create, update, and destroy actions? I would like to keep the scaffolding working as it does by default as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to see the code of Ryan Bates [nifty_scaffold generator](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/tree/master/rails_generators/nifty_scaffold).

He changed the scaffold to add more options and clean the create, update, and edit functions.

You can learn a lot from that.